# Firefox no sound Windows Server 2016 RDS

Tags: windows-server-2016, firefox, audio

No sound in Firefox version 57 and up in Windows Server 2016 Remote Desktop Services. Which means none of the users of RDS have sound when browsing with Firefox. Audio works, Google Chrome browser has sound just fine.

Problem is, Chrome is quirky on some proxy issues, Firefox being more stable makes it preferable for users.

The issue seemed to exist for Windows 10 and fixed (see [this link in Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1279227/firefox-no-sound-v57-0-2-in-windows-10-rs-prerelease-17063)).

It seems awkward that it isn't fixed in Windows Server, and / or that the Firefox bug fix for that issue wouldn't have been fixed by the Win 10 fix.

Any idea?

Comment: Report the bug to mozilla ?